# How to update a existing csv in google drive without using google sheets using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file (*data.csv*) in my Google drive.

I want to append new data (*df*) to that csv file(stack new below old as both csv's have same column headers) and save it to existing *data.csv* without using google sheets.

How can I do this?

Comment: In that case, I think that it is required to use the method of "Files: update" in Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) But unfortunately, I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open google colab and mount your google drive in colab using :

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Provide your authorization and the file will be available in your current session inside your drive directory. You can then edit the file by importing pandas or csv then :

```
with open('data.csv','a') as fd:
     fd.write(myCsvRow)
```

Opening a file with the 'a' parameter allows you to append to the end of the file instead of simply overwriting the existing content. Any changes you do will be saved to your original file.

Comment: hi akhil
how  to concat new df  to existing csv from drive , both have same column headers & save concated df  as csv (csv name should be same as old)

Comment: You can import pandas and use `pandas.concat` method . Refer to the pandas documentation to suit your work case : [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)